# ComboBox values are empty

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have the code below which is called when a selection is made in a `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`. I'm writing out some debug information to see what I've got to work with. The combo box correctly displays its contents. `Count` is correct. `SelectedIndex` is correct, i.e. it's value corresponds to that selected. However, `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue`, `SelectedText`, and `Text` are all blank. Why?

```
myComboBox_Contractors.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.bsContractor, "ContractorId", true));
myComboBox_Contractors.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
    ...  
        private void myComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var comboBox = sender as System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox;

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("comboBox: " + comboBox.Items.Count);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("comboBox.SelectedIndex: " + comboBox.SelectedIndex);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("comboBox.SelectedItem: " + comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("comboBox.SelectedValue: " + comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("comboBox.SelectedText: " + comboBox.SelectedText.ToString());
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("comboBox.Text: " + comboBox.Text.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: Try SelectedItem.ToString().  SelectedValue probably needs the ValueMember set when using a DataSource.  SelectedText is the highlighted portion of the text box.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx) : _" For example, if you retrieve the SelectedText value in a button Click event handler, the value will be an empty string. This is because the selection is automatically cleared when the input focus moves from the combo box to the button."_

Comment: I have populated a ComboBox with 5 strings - when I select a string the SelectedItem & Text properties are correctly set. SelectedText is blank for the reason above & SelectedValue is only set when you have data binding & as @LarsTech said the ValueMember needs to be set. What are you populating your ComboBox with?

Comment: @LarsTech: I added `ToString()` on your suggestion (modified code in the question). No effect.

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue, especially with the Text property.  You would have to post code that can duplicate the issue.

Comment: @PaulF: Does `SelectedIndexChanged` qualify as a "button Click event handler"?

Comment: and yes, using a DataSource (added that line of code).

Comment: Hmmm. `ValueMember` = "Id". I would have expected "ContractorId" based on the line that sets the DataBinding.

Comment: Ok, that was the problem. I had explicitly set `ValueMember` incorrectly.  So now `SelectedValue` is the same as `SelectedIndex` and `Text` is correct. `SelectedText` is still blank for the reasons above apparently. `SelectedItem` is still blank, but I've got enough to work with now. Thanks!. If someone wants to make an answer out of this, please do.

Comment: SelectedText contains whatever is currently selected - by clicking on another item in the drop-down you automatically clear the current selection hence the property is clear when you enter the SelectedIndexChanged event. I am still unsure why the SelectedItem appears blank - have you checked in the debugger if SelectedItem is set to anything - it could be that the default ToString for your object shows nothing - I have tried with strings & numbers & the value is correct.

Comment: You are correct. I can see a value for `SelectedItem` in the debugger (in the Watch window). I started doing the  `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine` because the Watch can be difficult to work with. Sometimes attempting to see the value in the Watch window causes VS to crash. And if not, it can take a minute or 2 to see its values. And then another minute if you want to scroll down to see more.